# breeze entitiesWithErrors not found but instead found entityErrors

Tags: breeze

The error object that is returned from breeze manager saveChanges() don't have the array entitiesWithErrors, but instead has the entityErrors array (perhaps is as it is on breeze.js version: 1.4.12, metadataVersion: 1.0.5)

The returned error object looks like...

Error {stack: "Error: Client side validation errors encountered", entityErrors: Array[6], message: "Client side validation errors encountered see the Errors collection on this object for more detail" entityErrors: Array[6] bla. bla..

Thus the code bellow will fail and I will need to refactor it if I am not able to work with entitiesWithErrors

```
function getErrorMessages(error) {
    function getValidationMessages(err) {
        try {
            return err.entitiesWithErrors.map(function (entity) {
                return entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors().map(function (valError) {
                    return valError.errorMessage;
                }).join('; <br/>');
            }).join('; <br/>');
        } catch (e) {

        }
        return 'validation error';
    }
    var msg = error.message;
    if (msg.match(/validation error/i)) {
        return getValidationMessages(error);
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This breaking change was made in Breeze version 1.4.0. From the release notes,

> The description of client side validation errors caught during a save
>   before posting to the server has changed.
>
> Client side validation errors caught during a save, but before posting
>   to the server, cause the save to fail and be routed to the fail
>   promise. The fail promise returns an error object that contains a
>   description of the errors. This description has changed.
>
> Previously this error object contained an entitiesWithErrors property
>   that contained a list of all of the entities that had failed
>   validation. This property has now been replaced with the entityErrors
>   property. The entityErrors property returns a collection of
>   entityError objects as described above.
>
> This change was made in order to retain consistency between save
>   failures that occurred on the server and those that failed before
>   posting to the server on the client.

To refactor your code, you simply do,

```
return error.entityErrors.map(function (entityError) {
  return entityError.errorMessage;
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. The idea I had in mind now is to notify the UI about validations error. I will do it following this pattern.

Comment: It works.
Thanks a lot!. 
Please more help.
The global idea I had in mind ,  is to notify the DOM about validations errors. I will follow this pattern.  1) configure the metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor for each entity with a custom entityInitializer function. 2) subscribe the validationErrorsChanged event inside this entityInitializer function. 3) publish the error PubSub.publish('validation error', validationChangeArgs).  4) and finally subscribe this message on a separate AMD module that will take care of decoding validationChangeArgs and update  the DOM
BUT

Comment: BUT I face two issues 1) I don’t have the reference of the DOM element with error (for user I could use JQuery and go find it) and 2) How can I validate DOM Elements that are not breeze entities, I mean , there is a way to use the breeze validator with ko.observables or DOM elements that ARE NOT breeze entities? Could I create such a FAKE breeze entity and apply validators to this fake. Ko.validation plugin validates observables, jquery validate plug in validates DOM Elements,  breeze validates remote server entities.

Comment: I love breezes because I don’t need to copy & paste to the client side the server validation rules, but in the case for example of  standard registration form, userid, password, confirm, password HTML inputs bind to ko observables, how can I use breeze validation engine to validate that form, i.e. query the database to test it is free the userid, check that the password is valid, and that the confirmation input exact match . I had done this with JQuery validate plugin, but wouldn’t like to have to validation engines JQuery (for DOM) and breeze (remote server entities)

Comment: Perhaps another idea could be read the breeze validator engine rules and “copy & paste” those on JQuery validate engine. But this will add an extra effort, when breeze is well doing his job, with the only exception that is not validating DOM elements nor ko  observables outside the breeze entities. Just few ideas will be appreciated BR